# getting a value from controller using jquery post

Tags: jquery, post, spring-mvc

Doing a post from jquery. POST is happening, but not able to access the model attribute added by controller.

JQuery Code:

```
$.post('<c:url value="/savedLog.form" />', $('#logForm').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
    var jsonlog = "${logJson}"
    if (data === "SUCCESS") {
        alert(jsonlog);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public String savedLog(@RequestParam(value = "requestId", required = true) LogRequest request, ModelMap model) throws IOException 
{
    try 
    {
        //Code to populate log            
        model.addAttribute("logJson", log.getLog());
        return "success";
    }​
}
```

POST is working fine and the controller method is executing successfully.There is a catch in actual code.Removed as it is redundant.

What could be the issue.
This line does not work.
    var jsonlog = "${logJson}"
    Is there any issue with model attribute or jquery?

Thank You.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more info. What do you mean by "this line does not work". Does the controller method get called at all, are there any errors, etc. You are not doing anything with the POSTed data? What about putting a `catch` after the `try` to see if something is failing there? @RequestParam binding is usually to String, int, long, boolean, etc., types, maybe Spring can't bind `LogRequest` to the `requestId` param? Do you have a view named "success" because that's what it looks like you are asking Spring to render to.

Comment: @nickdos: Updated the question with your queries. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing the request that generates your page (with the AJAX form in it) and the request that gets called when your AJAX POST happens.

```
var jsonlog = "${logJson}"
```

is only going to get populated on the first (page) request. The AJAX POST cannot inject JSTL values into your page once its rendered.

You need send that value in the response from your AJAX POST as text or JSON data and then  read that from the `data` var in the .POST callback. Add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to tell Spring to return JSON (may require adding Jackson library) and return a Map ...

```
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> savedLog(@RequestParam(value = "requestId", required = true) LogRequest request, ModelMap model) throws IOException {
try {
    //Code to populate log            
    //model.addAttribute("logJson", log.getLog());
    Map <String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("logJson", log.getLog());
    return map;
}​
```

then in the AJAX code, read:

```
$.post('<c:url value="/savedLog.form" />', $('#logForm').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {

    if (data.logJson) {
        alert(data.logJson);
    }
}, "json"); // Note JSON dataType specified here
```

Note: You shouldn't return "SUCCESS" as text from your controller. Use the HTTP codes for this, e.g. throw a 404 or 500 (via HttpServletResponse object) if an error occurs otherwise the status will automatically be 200 when your return your Map.

Comment: Thank You.But seems @ResponseBody is not supported in spring 2.5.6 which i am using. Is there any equivalent of this?

Comment: Sorry haven't used Spring 2.5 for years, you'll have to Google on how to produce JSON yourself. Next time you should mention you're using Spring 2.5.6, otherwise most people will assume you are using a recent version of Spring.